# Sticky footer A VERY small ISSUE

Tags: html, css

following is my code for sticky footer its working fine but i dont know why my sticky footer is not getting displayed at the center aligned position kindly let me know how can i modify it to accomplish my issue... Or is there ANY OTHER GOOD WAY TO MAKE THE STICKY FOOTER.
Thanks,

```
<table width="900" height="42" border="1" align="center" style="border-style:none; position: absolute;width: 900px;vertical-align: middle;text-align: center;z-index:999999999 !important;

    bottom: 0px;

" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#AEAEAE" bgcolor="#0C4549">
  <tr>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#0C4549" >2012 &copy; of DND CLUB. Developed by Radiations3.
        </div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Did you try margin:0 auto; in the style?

Comment: instead of using table, you could have used div, so that code would have less and styling would also be little easier compared to table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi check this one i hope this will work:-

```
<table width="100%" height="42" border="1" align="center" style="
position:absolute;
left:0;
right:0;
vertical-align:middle;
text-align:center;
bottom: 0px;
background:#0C4549;"
cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td align="center">2012 &copy; of DND CLUB. Developed by Radiations3.
        </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

demo:- http://jsfiddle.net/yFqPb/6/

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this. Much better solution.

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/

Also try to steer away from using tables for anything other than displaying tabular data.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `</div>` in `td`

```
<table width="900" height="42" border="1" align="center" style="border-style:none; position: absolute;width: 900px;vertical-align: middle;text-align: center;z-index:999999999 !important; bottom: 0px;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#AEAEAE" bgcolor="#0C4549">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="#0C4549" >2012 &copy; of DND CLUB. Developed by Radiations3.</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more all time proven solution for sticky footer.Its very simple to use and I use it often.

http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/